# Powershell Script get-uniq value from Tags

Tags: powershell

I have below query and script to get orphan AVsets from Azure and also I have added
resourcegroup tag "Owner" so can get owner of the resources and its working as expected.

I need to have some modification in code like.
I have 3 AVset and Owner is same and if I want to automate it, its sending 3 different mails so I want to have one mail and all resourcename in mail massage.
I am unable to sort -uniq

could you please help to have basic logic

support AV1 owner is 1
Av2 Owner also 1
so while sending mail it should check the Owner and send only one mail instead of 2 mails.

PowerShell Script

need basic logic so can amend further

```
`$info = @()
#$subscriptionids = Get-AzSubscription
$subscriptionids = "subids"
foreach($subscriptionid in $subscriptionids){
    Select-AzSubscription -Subscription $subscriptionid
   
#AvailabilitySet
$as = "resources
    | where type has 'Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets'
    | where properties.virtualMachines == '[]'
    | extend Details = pack_all()
    | project Resource=resourceGroup, name, type"
    $dt = Search-AzGraph -Subscription $subscriptionid -Query $as
    foreach($ct in $dt){
        $rdname = Get-AzResourceGroup $ct.Resource
        
         $info = new-object PSObject
         $info | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Resources" -Value $ct.name    
         $info | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "RGname" -Value $ct.Resource
         $info | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "ResourceType" -Value $ct.Type
         $info | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "Tag" -Value $rdname.Tags.Owner 
         $info

    }
   
}`
```

Comment: Use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to group the items in the whole collection on the `Tag` property: `$ar | Group-Object Tag`. Then loop over these groups and send all items in it to just the one owner.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

Without knowing what format your email should have, or what info is in the `Tag` (owner) property, here's how you can use [Group-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to send just one email to an owner.

```
$ar | Group-Object Tag | ForEach-Object {
    # $_ represents the current group you are iterating
    # $_.Name will be the items 'Tag' property that has the Owner

    $mailArgs = @{
        # just guessing that Tag has the emailaddress of the owner
        # otherwise you need to find it using whatever is in there
        To         = $_.Name
        From       = 'you@yourcompany.com'
        SmtpServer = 'smtp.yourcompany.com'
        Subject    = 'orphan AVsets'
        Body       = $_.Group | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
    }
    Send-MailMessage @mailArgs
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering, in $rdname.Tags.Owner  we have mail id of the rsg owner so can send mail on this mail id

Comment: @RakeshChaudhari Thanks for the feedback. Hopefully my answer helps solving your problem. If so, please have a quick look at the [tour] where you can learn how to mark a question 'done'